# Quartz in ASP.net Core project: how to get the scheduler instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an `ASP.net Core 6` project where I added `Quartz` to my services, like described here:

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/aspnet-core-integration.html#installation

This works and allows you to configure jobs and triggers during app startup.

However, what if I want to modify/add/remove a job or trigger while the app is running? I would need to retrieve the underlying `IScheduler` instance (ideally through the DI mechanism), but I don't know the proper way to do it in an ASP.net Core app.

So, how can you access the scheduler instance from DI in a .net core project?

Comment: Why not just have `IScheduler` as a parameter in the constructor of the class that wants to create a job?

Comment: @Neil: `IScheduler` is not added of the DI container, so you won't be able to inject it. I've found the proper solution, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the Quartz source code, I've understood how to do this.

Indeed, you cannot inject `IScheduler`, in fact it wouldn't make much sense because you can have multiple schedulers configured, so the DI container would have no way to decide which one to inject.

Instead, you need to inject `ISchedulerFactory`, which you can then use to retrieve one of the configured schedulers.

Example code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q => {
    //configuring basic Quartz settings...
}

//Other configs...

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var schedulerFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISchedulerFactory>();
    var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
}
```

Comment: I am looking for starting/stopping and passing parameters to jobs in my ASP Net Core application. Is it possible?

Comment: @Cenk: yes, as I wrote in the answer: inject the `ISchedulerFactory` in your controller (or wherever) and use it to obtain the instance of the `IScheduler`. Once you have it, you can use ti to trigger jobs and even register new jobs or remove them.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: Do you have any ideas for my requirement [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74403074/asp-net-core-2-1-calling-rest-api-in-a-schedule)